# How to retrieve additional JSON data from request in django ModelSerializer

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a model serializer that creates a Program object, along with another OutboundProgram object. The json I receive has all the details of a program object and the additional ones I need to create the OutboundProgram. How do I retrieve the additional fields because serializer only reads the fields for a certain object. P.S. our team lead doesnt want me to use a nested JSON

json received by the request:

```
{
"linkage": "AP",
"name": "something",
"academic_year": 2017,
"terms_available":[1,2],
"is_graduate": false,
"requirement_deadline":"2011-10-16",
"institution": 3
}
```

models.py

```
class Program(SoftDeletionModel):
    linkage = ForeignKey(Linkage)
    name = CharField(max_length=64)
    academic_year = ForeignKey(AcademicYear)
    terms_available = ManyToManyField(Term)
    is_graduate = BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class OutboundProgram(SoftDeletionModel):
    program = ForeignKey(Program)
    requirement_deadline = DateField()
    institution = ForeignKey(Institution)
```

serializers.py

```
class OutboundProgramSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        terms = validated_data.pop('terms_available')
        program = Program.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for term in terms:
            program.terms_available.add(term)
        program.save()

        outbound_program = OutboundProgram.objects.create(program=program)
        #how to assign outbound_program.requirements_deadline from json
        return program
```

Any kind of help would be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use [extra-context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context):

```
request = self.context['request']
terms = request.data.get('terms_available', [])
```

Comment: glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

**serializers.py**

```
class OutboundProgramSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    requirement_deadline = serializers.DateField(write_only=True)
    institution = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        terms = validated_data.pop('terms_available')
        program = Program.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for term in terms:
            program.terms_available.add(term)
        program.save()

        outbound_program = OutboundProgram.objects.create(program=program)
        outbound_program.requirement_deadline = validated_data.pop('requirement_deadline')
        outbound_program.institution_id = validated_data.pop('institution')
        outbound_program.save()
        return program
```

Comment: I dont think this will work validated_data doesnt include the 2 extra fields it will just return a key error